# Select column in TadvMemo

Tags: delphi, tms

Is it possible to select a column text area in a TadvMemo component? 
Like selecting text in Delphi IDE holding the left mouse button and the ALT-key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch to the block selection mode by setting the `SelectionMode` property to `smBlock`.

```
AdvMemo1.SelectionMode := smBlock;
```

Comment: this feature was introduced in TAdvMemo v.3.0.0.0 (TMS Component Pack 6.4.0.0). You can specify selection by using `SelStartX`/`SelStartY` and `SelEndX`/`SelEndY`  properties